# Why is the return type of std::rand() not an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, random

[std::rand](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) said,

> `int rand();`
> Returns a pseudo-random integral value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX (​0​ and RAND_MAX included).

Since it is guaranteed that a non-negative integer will be returned, why the return type is signed?

I am not talking about if we should use it here. Is it a historical issue or some bad design?

Comment: Possibly because int was considered a first-class type in the old days. (K&R C legacy ?) Notice that relatively few languages support unsigned types.

Comment: If `RAND_MAX` is less than 2^31 (and usually its much less) there's no benefit to it being unsigned, there are downsides like if someone does `rand() % 100 - 50` they might get surprising results

Comment: Note that rand() is a very old function. It was definitely here before C was standardized. It is possible it was created even before unsigned ints were added to the language.

Comment: It's historical.  (Going from memory) `rand()`/`srand()` were specified before C supported unsigned (or long!) types. At that time, most C implementations had a 16-bit `int` and only a few had a 32-bit `int`, which is why `RAND_MAX` is only required to be 32767 (or more). Unsigned and long types (among other things) were introduced when Unix was rewritten in C (in 1973). Subsequent evolutions of C (including the C89 standard) maintained backward compatibility, and the first C++ standard (according to the ARM) was required to maintain compatibility to C89 where possible.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is much debate about `unsigned`. Without going too much into subjective territory, consider the following: What matters is not whether the value returned from `rand()` cannot be negative. What matters is that `rand()` returns a value of a certain type and that type determines what you can do with that value. `rand()` never returns a negative value, but does it make sense to apply operations on the value that make the value negative? Certainly yes. For example you might want to do:

```
 auto x = rand() % 6 - 3;
```

If `rand()` would return an `unsigned` then this would lead to confusing bugs in code that looks ok.

Using `unsigned` for example for indices is a different story. An index is always positive. If you want to apply operations to it that turn the value negative then it is not an index anymore. `rand() % 6 -3` on the other hand is a random number, be it positive or not.

A type is more than the range of values it can represent. Signed and unsigned integers have different semantics.

Note that C++20 introduced [`std::ssize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). It's the size of a container, it can only be positive. Nevertheless it is signed. That's one example for positive values that are  signed merely to allow signed arithmetics. Also it was not an option to change `std::size` to return a signed, because that would break existing code.

And as a sidenote consider that Java has no unsigned integer type at all, because unsigned arithmetics were considered too confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Alan and you give a similar example to prove that use unsigned is even worse here. Like you said, what matters is the type but not the value. If rand is unsiged, I will definitely don't do the minus. It's something you could avoid by being careful. It could also have the same problem when using `std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigend int>`. Please correct me if I am something wrong.

Comment: @Nimrod when you use `std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>` then you are specifically asking for unsigned. Being careful is not the best solution to avoid bugs. `size()` being unsigned is a good example. `for (int i= container.size()-1; i>=0; --i)` looks correct but it is not (if `container` is empty the loop will go havoc). The author did not explicitly ask for unsigned when they used `size()-1` but thats what they get

Comment: "Java has no unsigend integer type at all". Alas, the Java `char` is a 16 bit unsigned type.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why alas?  I believe that Java's `char` type represents a UTF-16 code unit, and as such _needs_ to be unsigned.

Comment: It might be worth making explicit that the problems everyone's referring to are specifically about the fact that any negative values are wrapped around to +UINT_MAX. The problem being that you then have positive values again – in signed arithmetic, negatives may very well also be nonsensical, but at least it's easier to figure out the bug. — Arguably, the default behaviour for unsigned types should instead be an exception if any attempted arithmetic would result in negatives – just, that's not an option for C++ for performance reasons.

Comment: @Bathsheba: IMHO, there was never any reason for Java not to include both 8-bit and 16-bit unsigned types, since all types smaller than 32 bits will promote to `int`.  Nearly all of the "problems" with unsigned types stem from ambiguity as to how promotions and balancing should be performed in contexts that mix signed and unsigned types, but for smaller unsigned types such issues simply don't exist.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Java `char` is not intended to be used for arithmetic.

Comment: @supercat: "all types smaller than 32 bits will promote to `int`." is not true in C and doesn't mean the same thing in Java, because integer promotion in Java doesn't have the signedness consideration.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I was talking about integer promotion in Java, and the fact that all types smaller than `int` are going to promote to `int`, and could do so whether they were signed or unsigned.  The reason unsigned types are problematic in C is that unsigned types that aren't smaller than `int` can't use the same promotion rules as those that are.

Comment: "A type is more than the range of values... different semantics". Coming from JS (~untyped lang), this strikes me as a valuable insight.

Comment: @Bathsheba, `char` may be an *unsigned* type, but is it an *integer* type?  Can you perform the full set of arithmetic operations on it?

Comment: @Mark According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1), `char` is indeed an unsigned integral type, with range `'\u0000'` to `'\uFFFF'`. It is subject to normal promotion rules when used in arithmetic contexts.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, `std::ssize_t` is only new to ISO C++.  POSIX C has had `ssize_t` for a long time, e.g. as the return type of the [`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system call.  On many systems it's the same type as `ptrdiff_t`, but a system where the max object size is significantly smaller than the total address-space (e.g. because of a non-flat memory model) might have a wider `ptrdiff_t`.  But it might not, because it's only well-defined behaviour to subtract pointers into the same object, so IDK.  (Use `intptr_t` to subtract unrelated ptrs.)

Comment: I would think if anything `ssize_t` should be wider than `ptrdiff_t`.  From a usability standpoint, a system that can guarantee that in all cases where `ptr2=ptr1+unsignedDelta` is defined,  `(size_t)(ptr2-ptr1)` will yield `unsignedDelta` without making `ptrdiff_t` be larger than `size_t` will  often be more useful than one which makes `ptrdiff_t` a larger type, even if `unsignedDelta` could be larger than `PTRDIFF_MAX`.

Answer (score 10):

Stroustrup writes in "The C++ Programming Language: 6.2.4 Integer Types":
*The **unsigned** integer types are ideal for uses that treat storage as a bit array. Using an **unsigned** instead of an **int** to gain one more bit to represent positive integers is almost never a good idea. **Attempts to ensure that some values are positive by declaring variables unsigned will typically be defeated by the implicit conversion rules.**