# Why does std::match_results.position() return a difference_type?

Tags: c++, regex, std

I'm trying to compare a regex match to a position in a string. My position is a `std::size_t` since AFAIK that's what you use to index something.  But `match_results.position()` returns a `difference_type` and the comparison results in a sign conversion warning. Getting the warning itself makes sense given the different types.

On a conceptual level though it doesn't make sense to me why the types are different in the first place. How could a match result have a negative position?  For that matter, what's a good/sane way to do this task?  Just cast it?

If this is a duplicate I apologize, I failed at searching.

Something like:

```
std::string str = "aaaba";
std::regex pattern("b");
std::smatch match;
std::regex_search(str, match, pattern);
std::cout << "Position: " << match.position() << std::endl; // works fine

// in real life ref would be a function parameter
std::size_t ref = 2;

if (match.position() > ref) {  // warning happens here
    std::cout << "After." << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Before." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I don’t think there’s a practical use for this interface, but it makes sense from an implementation point of view, since `position()` returns the difference between the offset of the first character of the match, and of the submatch. Offset differences can be negative and are therefore signed (but not in this case, since the submatch always comes at or after the begin of the entire match). — Still, the implementation should not dictate the interface.

Comment: I think it simply comes from the fact that the type of `size_t1 - size_t2` is `difference_type`. This happens to be equivalent to `size_t` when `size_t1 > size_t2`, as in the regexp situation, but that's not always the case.

Comment: reminds me of this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/71306268/4117728. It doesnt have to be negative for it to make sense to have a sign. Suppose you make two regex serches and want to compare the resulting positions `match1.position() - match2.position()` would be  a potential bug when it was unsigned (unless you know already that `match1.position() > match2.position()`)

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have expected `position()` to return something like an index.  At any rate I'll just `static_cast` the result to `size_t` for my purposes.  Thanks, y'all.